# Where does Fluid.app put the console log?

Tags: macos, fluid-mac-app-engine

I see a template in the user scripts where it points to `console.log('foobar');` as an example filename for the console log.

WHERE, exactly can I find this console log? I tried looking in ~/library/application support and had a rummage around. Couldn’t find it. Where can I find the file `console.log` or `foobar` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Developer of [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com) here. Use:

```
Main Menu > Window > Show Error Console
```

or

```
⎇⌘C
```

This will make the standard [WebKit Web Inspector](https://www.webkit.org/blog/2518/state-of-web-inspector/) appear with the Console displayed.

Messages sent to `window.console.log()` will appear there (along with other messages from WebKit).

Comment: Todd, what is `foobar` all about? Do we need to enter a unique word (like “foobar”) for each Greasekit script?

Comment: What happens if I delete the line that says `console.log('foobar’)`? is it optional? [for example, if I don’t care about error logs]

Comment: @HannahEllis That is example code that simply logs a string. You may delete it.

Comment: Hey Todd, could you please help with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20260676/how-can-i-get-fluid-app-to-support-gm-xmlhttprequest - it’s about Fluid specifically.